# Sumar días hábiles a mi fecha actual PHP

Tags: php

Hola buenas necesito ayuda con un código, estoy trabajando con envió y recepción de carátulas, el problema que tengo es que al recibir debo sumarle X días a la fecha de recepción dependiendo del estado que tenga cada carátula (3-4-5 días etc..) estos días deben ser hábiles no contar sábados y domingos, debe ser PHP puro sin funciones ya que al recibir múltiples carátulas no funcionaria. Esto es algo de código que tengo.

```
$plazo = intval($row7[0]['ESTAD_PLAZO']);
if ($plazo != 0 || $plazo != "") {
   $prox_aviso = date("Y-m-d");
   $i = 0; 
   while ($i < $plazo) {

        $dia = date("w", strtotime($prox_aviso));

        if ($dia != 6 || $dia != 0) {

          $i++;

        }

        $date_future = strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($prox_aviso));
        $prox_aviso = date('Y-m-d', $date_future);

   }
}
```

Adjunto el código completo de la recepción de carátulas el actual codigo me cuenta los dias por ej si el plazo es 3 los sum apero contando sabados y domingos.

```
$caratulasRecibir=explode("-", $_POST["caratulasRecibir"]);
for ($i=0; $i < count($caratulasRecibir); $i++) {

    $sql10 = "SELECT * FROM `sg_ptt_flujo` WHERE FLU_PAQ='".$caratulasRecibir[$i]."';";
    $row10 = Connection($sql10);
    $quien = $row10[0]["FLU_ORIG"];
    $que = 'RECIBIO CARATULA DE'." ".$quien;

    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO `sg_bitacora` (`bita_quien`,`bita_hizo`,`bita_peti`,`bita_orig`,`bita_obser`,`bita_cuando`,`bita_nbr_equip`,`bita_ip_equip`)
    VALUES ('".$_SESSION["usu"]."', '".$que."', '".$caratulasRecibir[$i]."', '".$row10[0]["FLU_PAQesta"]."', '".$row10[0]["FLU_OBS"]."', '".$fechacuando."', '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."', '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."');";
    $row2 = Connection($sql2);

    $sql = "UPDATE sg_ptt SET PET_LOCALIZ='".$_SESSION["usu"]."' WHERE `PET_NUM` = '".$caratulasRecibir[$i]."';";
    $row = Connection($sql);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM sg_ptt WHERE `PET_NUM` = '".$caratulasRecibir[$i]."';";
    $row1 = Connection($sql);

    $sql="SELECT * FROM `sg_ptt_flujo` WHERE FLU_PAQ='".$caratulasRecibir[$i]."';";
    $row=Connection($sql);
   

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `sg_ptt_flujo_hist` (`FLU_FCH`,`FLU_ORIG`,`FLU_MOV`,`FLU_DEST`,`FLU_PAQ`,`FLU_PAQesta`,`FLU_PAQfee`,`FLU_OBS`,`FLU_IP_ORIG`,`FLU_EQ_ORIG`,`FLU_IMPORTANTE`,`FLU_DETALL_IMPORT`)
    VALUES ('".$row[0]["FLU_FCH"]."', '".$row[0]["FLU_DEST"]."', 'RECIBIÓ DE', '".$row[0]["FLU_ORIG"]."', '".$row[0]["FLU_PAQ"]."', '".$row1[0]["PET_ESTADO"]."', '".$row1[0]["PET_FCH_ESTI_ENTRG"]."', '".$row1[0]["PET_IMPORTANT_GLOSA"]."', '".$row[0]["FLU_IP_ORIG"]."', '".$row[0]["FLU_EQ_ORIG"]."', '".$row[0]["FLU_IMPORTANTE"]."', '".$row[0]["FLU_DETALL_IMPORT"]."');";
    $row=Connection($sql);
  
 
    $sql="DELETE FROM `sg_ptt_flujo` WHERE `FLU_PAQ` = '".$caratulasRecibir[$i]."';";
    $row=Connection($sql);
    
    $sql7 = "SELECT * FROM sg_ptt_tbl_estad_trab WHERE ESTAD_GLOSA = '".$row1[0]["PET_ESTADO"]."'";
    $row7 = Connection($sql7);
    $plazo = intval($row7[0]['ESTAD_PLAZO']);

    if ($plazo != 0 || $plazo != "") {  

      $prox_aviso = date("Y-m-d");
      $i = 0; 
      while ($i < $plazo) {

        $dia = date("w", strtotime($prox_aviso));

        if ($dia != 6 || $dia != 0) {

          $date_future = strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($prox_aviso));
          $prox_aviso = date('Y-m-d', $date_future);
          $i++;

        } else {

          $date_future = strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($prox_aviso));
          $prox_aviso = date('Y-m-d', $date_future);

        }

      }


    }

    if ($plazo == 0 || $plazo == "") {
      $prox_aviso = "";
    }

    $sql8 = "UPDATE sg_ptt SET PET_FCH_ESTI_ENTRG2 = '".$prox_aviso."' WHERE `PET_NUM` = '".$caratulasRecibir[$i]."';";
    $row8 = Connection($sql8);
    
}
```

Comment: ¿Por qué debe ser sin funciones, es parte de una tarea?

Comment: eh intentado con funciones, pero funciona al recibir solamente de una, cuando son mas de 1 siempre me lanza errores

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estás incrementando `$i`, pero eso no afecta los días agregados, por el contrario, disminuyes la cantidad de iteraciones en el ciclo.

```
$plazo = intval($row7[0]['ESTAD_PLAZO']);
$prox_aviso = '';
if ($plazo > 0) {
   $prox_aviso = date("Y-m-d");
   $dia = date("w", strtotime($prox_aviso));
   // Solo analizas si es día inhábil
   for($i = 0; $i < $plazo; $i++) {
        if ($dia == 0 || $dia == 6) {
          // Incrementas los días de plazo
          $plazo ++;
        }
        // Incrementar día
        $dia ++;
        // Reiniciar día si es necesario
        if($dia > 6) {
            $dia = 0;
        }
   }
   // Sumas los días a la fecha
   $date_future = strtotime("+$plazo days", strtotime($prox_aviso));
   $prox_aviso = date('Y-m-d', $date_future);
}
```

Puedes poner esto dentro de una función, solo envía el parámetro correcto:

```
// Función forzando que el parámetro sea entero
function proxAviso($plazo) {
    $prox_aviso = '';
    if ($plazo > 0) {
        $prox_aviso = date("Y-m-d");
        $dia = date("w", strtotime($prox_aviso));
        // Solo analizas si es día inhábil
        for($i = 0; $i < $plazo; $i++) {
            if ($dia == 0 || $dia == 6) {
                // Incrementas los días de plazo
                $plazo ++;
            }
            // Incrementar día
            $dia ++;
            // Reiniciar día si es necesario
            if($dia > 6) {
               $dia = 0;
            }
        }
        // Sumas los días a la fecha
        $date_future = strtotime("+$plazo days", strtotime($prox_aviso));
        $prox_aviso = date('Y-m-d', $date_future);
    }
    return $prox_aviso;
}
```

Simplemente la ejecutas así:

```
$prox_aviso = proxAviso((intval($row7[0]['ESTAD_PLAZO']));
```